# Prove: $|f|=|g|$ on border of unit disc, then there is constant $n$ with $|n|=1$, such that $f=ng$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc and f and g are holomorphic on an area of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and do not have any zeros on $\mathbb{D}$.
How can I prove that if $|f|=|g|$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ then there is a constant with the propertiees above. 
The hint is to first assume that there are no zeros on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ of $g$. I guess no I can look at $\left|\frac{f}{g}\right|=1$. As a holomorphic function I could use the maximum principle that this is the maximum of the function, since $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic. How can I continue from here on? And how can I then leave the restriction to $g$ off?

Comment: For your idea: You've proven that $f/g$ is constant on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. Denote this constant by $c$ and consider $h:=f/g-c$. What happens if you apply the maximum modulus principle to this function?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @copper.hat  Thanks for the comment, I corrected the question.

Comment: What would $| { g \over f } | $ be?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I know that $h\equiv 0$. By that I know that, $|f/g|=|c|=1$ and therefore $f=cg$, right?

Comment: @ChessBaker251 Well, the middle conclusion with the absolute value doesn't imply the latter conclusion without it, but you're correct that $h\equiv 0$ implies $f=cg$.

Comment: I gave a solution here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631621/show-two-analytic-functions-are-related-by-a-constant/

Comment: @user8675309 in our lecture, we haven't tolkaed about meromorphic functions..

Comment: @WoolierThanThou what I yet don't see is, how I can leave the assumption $g(z)\neq 0$ on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$. Could I use that, $h$ has a removable singularity? I wouldn't see how.

Comment: @ChessBaker251 -- you don't need to know what a meromorphic function is.  You just need to know what a rational function is and what an analytic function is (with particular emphasis on a locally non-zero analytic function), then reason that their product cannot have an essential singularity.